# how to check the dynamic behavior of a web service (WCF) from process monitor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, process, fiddler

I need to monitor the behavior of a web service (**WCF**) that has been successfully published on my desktop with IIS6.

It was built by C# in VS2013 on win7.

I need to consume/access the service from my laptop by downloading a file from the web service.

```
 WebClient.DownloadFile(myUri, myFile);
```

This is called from a c# VS 2010.

I have installed fiddler, MS process explorer and cygwin (watch "ps -W")  in order to monitor what has happened when

```
DownloadFile()
```

was executed.

But, in all the process monitors, I cannot see any dynamic update for behavior of my desktop which is the service host.

**-----update ----**

I want to monitor the process of how the host transfer the data to the client, becasue in client (my laptop), the DownloadFile() cannot download any files larger than 64KB. I also found that on the server side (my desktop), even thought I set maxRequestLength = 1 in wbe.config, I can still download files as long as they are smaller than 64KB. So, I think that the desktop must have some default setting to overwrite the max file size that is allowed to download.

I have checked all setting of timeout, minBytePerSec, maxrequestlength, weblimit of IIS and web.config on client and server (my desktop). None of them can solve the problem.

**When I copied the code and debug it in my desktop, I got error** of

```
 "The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout."
```

**But, when I run the same program from my laptop. No these errors.**

In Fiddler, I got

```
[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 65536 bytes.
```

Comment: What behavior do you want to monitor? Also, is this an ASMX service?

Comment: You say you're not seeing anything with Fiddler. Do you see the request to the server? If you see the request, but don't see anything else, then the server isn't _sending_ anything else. It's broken. You'll have to debug it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, i do not see the request. I am new to fiddler. I also found that on the server side (my desktop), even thought I set axRequestLength = 1 in wbe.config, I can still download files as long as they are smaller than 64KB.

Comment: First step is to figure out how Fiddler works or some other network monitor and to see what's going on with the wire. There's really very little to discuss until you know what's going on. Have you tried debugging the server and setting breakpoints to make sure the client call even gets through?

Comment: And, there's no "process monitor" which will do what you want. You need a network monitor to see what's happening on the network, and/or a debugger to find out what your code is doing.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I have debugged to the C# code on my laptop that need to consume the web service hosted on my desktop. The file can be downloaded as long as it is smaller than 64 KB.

Comment: And, what happens when the file is larger? Is an exception thrown? And I meant debugging the _service_ hosted on your desktop.

Comment: Can fiddler help me find the process of the host transfering data file to laptop ?

Comment: I don't understand. How can you not know which process your service is running in? Is there some reason you can't use the debugger on the service?

Comment: I am using VS2010 to debug the C# code on my laptop. My service is on desktop. You mean I debug in my desktop ? But, I just published the service (by ClickOnce) to my desktop. There are only some dll files and web.config files on my desktop. The service consumer is on my laptop.

Comment: Then run the service in Debug mode, from Visual Studio, on the desktop.

Comment: This can help me debug into the desktop process that handle the process of transfering data to laptop ? what is the difference between debug in laptop and desktop ?

Comment: Don't debug _into_ it. That's too fancy. Just start Visual Studio, open the project, press F5, and set a breakpoint on the method where it starts doing the download.

Comment: Ok, I have done this on my laptop. I will do it on my desktop. Just want to know the difference.

Comment: @John Saunders, I got error of "An exception occurred during a WebClient request. " and "Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section."   "InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException". Message=An invalid argument was supplied. But, when I run the same program from my laptop. No these errors.

Comment: @John Saunders, I have fixed the defaultProxy configuration problem. Now, I got new error:   "The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout."